# ¿Cómo reiniciar un juego web?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando un juego tipo Wordle, para aprender las bases de HTML, CSS y Javascript. Ya he podido realizar el funcionamiento básico del juego. En [GitHub](https://brmiete.github.io/WordlePPY/) pueden ver mis avances.

Al terminar el juego (ya sea que el usuario gane o pierda), quiero mostrar un botón para "reiniciar" el juego, es decir, para que el usuario lo intente de nuevo.
La solución que se me ocurrió fue recargar la página web al hacer clic en el botón de "Jugar de nuevo", mediante un botón en el HTML y una función de refresh ligada al mismo.

Esto escribí en el botón del HTML:

```
<button id="reset" type="submit" onClick="refreshPage()">Jugar de nuevo</button>
```

Y esta función para recargar la página web:

```
function refreshPage(){
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Sé que existen varias maneras de lograr el mismo resultado, y aunque cumple el propósito, quisiera saber si hay otra forma más "profesional" de reiniciar el juego.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu problema es algo amplio ya que implica lógica de programación y no un error per se, así las soluciones que podamos darte serán más de opinión, tendrías que especificar más qué problema tienes al intentar reiniciar tu juego. A grandes rasgos te sugeriría que al presionar el botón reinicies el contador de intentos, limpies la grilla de intentos y selecciones una nueva palabra. Si te bloqueas intentando hacer eso ya puedes volver con una pregunta más específica.

Comment: Reiniciar un juego implica reiniciar el `estado` del juego. Setea las variables a su valor por defecto y efectivamente habrás refrescado el juego.